# how to define typescript interface with different schemas?

Tags: typescript

Im trying to define `Consume` type with 2 different payloads.

```
interface Eat {
  category: 'meat' | 'vegetable'
}
interface Drink {
  size: string
}
interface Consume {
   type: 'eat' | 'drink'
   payload: Eat | Drink
}
```

when i try if statements

```
function doSomething(c: Consume): string {
   if (c.type === 'Eat') {
      const e: Eat = c.payload            <----- ERRORS
      return e.category
   }
   return ''
}
```

errors with
`Type Eat | Drink is not assignable to type 'Drink'. Property 'size' is missing in type 'Eat' but required in type 'Drink'. ts(2322)`

Is it possible to have 2 distinct schemas in a typescript interface `Consume` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```
interface Eat {
  category: 'meat' | 'vegetable'
}
interface Drink {
  size: string
}
interface Consume {
   type: 'eat' | 'drink'
   payload: Eat | Drink
}

function doSomething(c: Consume): string {
   if (c.type === 'eat') {
      const e: Eat = c.payload as Eat;
      return e.category;
   }
   return ''
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i ended up having to rearrange it. typescript was able to detect the schema change with the format below without having to use `X as typeY`

```
type Consume = Eat | Drink

interface Eat {
  type: 'eat'
  payload: EatPayload
}
interface EatPayload {
   category: 'meat' | 'vegetable'
}

interface Drink {
  type: 'drink'
  payload: DrinkPayload
}
interface DrinkPayload {
  size: string
}

function doSomething(c: Consume): string {
   if (c.type === 'eat') {
      return c.payload.category;
   }
   return ''
}
```